# Adding a column to custom piped function

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am new to making functions that take advantage of `%>%` in R.

Given the following data

```
sim <- tribble(~x,~n,1,1,1,2,1,3)
```

I would like to make a function that adds a column like so

```
>sim <- sim %>% mutate(sum = x+n)
>sim
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      x     n   sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2
2     1     2     3
3     1     3     4
```

This is as far as made it

```
addr <- function(tbl, x, n){tbl <- mutate(sumr=tbl$x+tbl$n)}
sim <- tribble(~x,~n,1,1,1,2,1,3)
sim %>% addr(x,n)
```

The problem is that I am not adding a column onto the piped table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a function using the tidy way

```
addr <- function(dat, col1, col2) {
  col1 <- enquo(col1)
  col2 <- enquo(col2)
  dat %>%
       mutate(sum = (!!col1) + (!!col2))
}

addr(sim, x, n)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     n   sum
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     2
#2     1     2     3
#3     1     3     4
```

Comment: This is great! I have never seen `enquo` or  `!!`. Where can I find more documentation?

Comment: @Alex new version of dplyr https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/

Comment: Also see the [dplyr programming vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

Comment: This still does not seem to add the data to the original table. For example `sim %>% addr(x,n)` followed by `sim` yields only a 2 column table not 3 columns.

Comment: @Alex You need to assign it to original data i.e. `sim <- addr(sim, x, n)`.   There is also the magrittr operator `%<>%` which does it.